# Display specific data in other model

Tags: python, django, django-models

how to display specific data in other model in django
here my code in my models.py

```
class ProjectName(models.Model):
    BacProjectName = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    date_created: object = models.DateField(auto_now=True)



 def __str__(self):
        return self.BacProjectName

class BacFileUpload(models.Model):
    Sproject = models.ForeignKey(ProjectName__date_created__year=2019, 
     on_delete=models.CASCADE)



  Sproject = models.ForeignKey(ProjectName__date_created__year=2019, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'to'
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Display specific data in other model" but it looks like you're using the ForeignKey incorrectly.  Your first argument must be the name of the Model or the model itself. This is the reason why you get a TypeError. For more information please look at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey It's a well documentated topic.